# Add a dynamic day value to a date in xquery

Tags: xquery

I am trying to find the date of "sunday" in the current week. This is the code, I have:

```
let $today := fn:current-date()
let $day-week := functx:day-of-week($today)
let $start-date := xs:date($today)-xs:dayTimeDuration($day-week)
```

$today -> has today's date
$day-week -> is 5 (value for friday)

I thought, when I did $today-5, I will get 7/14/2013.

But, this didn't work. Kindly correct my code. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`functx:day-of-week($today)` returns an `xs:integer` which won't cast into an `xs:dayTimeDuration`. Just multiply that integer by a valid duration instead of casting:

```
let $today := fn:current-date()
let $day-week := functx:day-of-week($today)
let $start-date := xs:date($today)-($day-week*xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think xs:dayTimeDuration needs a bit more setting up. Try it something like this:

```
let $today := fn:current-date()
let $day-week := functx:day-of-week($today)
let $start-date := xs:date($today)-(xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')*$day-week)
```

Get more information here:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.xml%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_xsdaytimeduration.htm